# Organize shared code between androidTest and test

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-testing, robolectric

I'm building an android component in the form of a gradle project. To test my components UI in several configurations with the [espresso](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/index.html) framework, I have a `TestActivity` in the `androidTest` source set, which I can instrument.

To clarify the file tree:

```
src/
    androidTest/
        java/my.package/
            TestActivity.kt
            ...
        res/layout/
            my_test_activitity.xml
    test/
        java/my.package/
            MyUnitTests.kt
```

Now I want to start using [robolectric](http://robolectric.org/) for some of my unit tests and also test my `TestActivity` from there.
Interestingly, Android Studio doesn't complain when I setup Robolectric in `MyUnitTests.kt`:

```
val activity = Robolectric.setupActivity(TestActivity::class.java) // no error
```

However, when I try to run the unit tests, gradle is presenting me with this error:

```
e: src/test/java/my.package/MyUnitTests.kt: Unresolved reference: TestActivity
```

My guess is that the `test` source set does not have access to the `androidTest` source set, even though Android Studio seems to think it has.

How can I fix this (make classes and resources in `androidTest` accessible from `test`)? Is this even the correct approach when sharing code between instrumentation tests and unit tests or is there a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I often get around this by creating a src/commonTest/java sourceset and expose that to both the instrumentation tests and unit tests by adding the following to my gradle file:

```
  android {
    sourceSets {
        String sharedTestDir = 'src/commonTest/java'
        test {
            java.srcDir sharedTestDir
        }
        androidTest {
            java.srcDir sharedTestDir
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it doesnt work for me, i tried it this way. And it keeps telling me the code does not exist

Comment: @LenaBru can you post an image showing your directory structure and the code to set this up from your gradle file?

Answer (score 0):

The accepted solution works great for normal Gradle scripts. However, for anyone using the Gradle Kotlin DSL (*.kts files) this should do the trick.

```
sourceSets {
    val sharedTestDir = "src/sharedTest/java"
    getByName("test") {
        java.srcDir(sharedTestDir)
    }
    getByName("androidTest") {
        java.srcDirs(sharedTestDir)
    }
}
```